# -e option in command grep

Tags: grep, syntax

I encountered a problem when reading `grep` manual refering to it `-e` option,
It say:

```
-e pattern, --regexp=pattern
         Specify a pattern used during the search of the input: an input
         line is selected if it matches any of the specified patterns.
         This option is most useful when multiple -e options are used to
         specify multiple patterns, or when a pattern begins with a dash
         (`-').
```

I'm confused about what's the `e` short for? There's not an answer could searched by google.
Additionally, it's easy to understand that

> "This option is most useful when multiple -e options are used to specify multiple patterns"

but what does this mean?

> "or when a pattern begins with a dash (`-')."

Could you please show an example?

Comment: e for expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"e for expression" is a reasonable interpretation, especially in contrast to the `-E` flag for Extended Regular Expression (ERE) which is available in at least some versions of `grep`.

Multiple `-e` flags may be used to match any of multiple expressions, e.g.:

```
# grep -e "nodes" -e "routers" /etc/hosts
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

And `-e` allows for patterns that begin with a dash, so that `grep` doesn't try to interpret the pattern as an option/flag:

```
# grep -e "-all" /etc/hosts
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
ff02::3         ip6-allhosts
```